# X2 Engine - users different than admin can't see contacts

Tags: php

i've tried to find an answer to this question google-ing, and i was only able to find one answer that suited but, unfortunately, the patch suggested didn't work. That's why i'm placing this question here.

i'm using X2 engine v4.3 and i've recently discovered that a user (any user created by admin) is not able to view the contact information.
He/she's able to edit it, but when an opening attempt is made, the result is:

Send Error Report
Here's a quick list of what will be included in the report:

Error Code: 404
Error Message: Unable to resolve the request "contacts/id/index".
Stack Trace: [click to toggle display]
0 /var/www/vhosts/URL/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('contacts/id/ind...')
1 /var/www/vhosts/URL/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
2 /var/www/vhosts/URL/index.php(55): CApplication->run()
3 {main} 
X2Engine Version: 4.3
PHP Version: 5.4.33

The administrator user is able to see and modify contacts with no problem. 
The strange part is that in localhost this error doesn't happen, the user is able to see the information, this error is happening in the web server.

Does someone has any ideia on how to fix this?

any help would be highly appreciatted.

thank you,